# My Employer Contribution each year Using W2 form

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution, form-w-2, employer-match

I contribute to my 401K each month but I am not sure how much my employer is contributing each year to my 401K.

They said they will match 5% of my salary but I am not able to find that number in my W2 form.

I have a W2 form. Can you share how to find my employer contribution towards my 401K each year?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience it isn't on the standard W-2 form. The amount of matching funds aren't generally of interest to the IRS. The amount of matching funds isn't reported on your 1040 form.

The two places I find the amount of matching funds are:

- On each pay check stub. In a comments section they mention the amount of contribution they made. They generally also have a Year to date total for their contribution.
- On the website for the 401K program every contribution from the employee and the employer should be listed. There should also be an activity section that allows you to see how much was contributed from each source. In my experience they also generate quarterly and annual statements even if most participants ask for electronic statements only. The statements can be downloaded/displayed as a PDF.

One advantage of the website is that some companies also include a portion of the profit sharing  as a 401 contribution. Since the profit sharing contribution isn't triggered by a paycheck there might not be a mention of it on any pay stub.